# Where to validate in relation to other models

Tags: validation, django-rest-framework

I use Django REST Framework and I have a model that represents bookings for a room:

```
class Booking(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    begin_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

Bookings are not allowed to overlap in time. So I have to compare the dates the user wants to book the room for with all previous bookings.

I could validate this

- in my `serializers.ModelSerializer` class using a validator, but my validation is not really about sanitizing
- in the `ModelViewSet` in the `create` method of `CreateModelMixin` or
- in the `Booking`-Model when saving using the `save` method.

What would be the way the Django REST Framework developers intended for this specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually solve this by rewriting my view's create / update to call some business or extra validation steps before calling the serializer's save.

Comment: -1 If you put that logic in the view it means that you'd have to ALWAYS use that view to create the model. For example validation wont be called if you use the django admin or if you create it manually in the console, and you'll break your data integrity. You should keep skinny views and fat models http://django-best-practices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applications.html#make-em-fat

Comment: Please, read more carefully. you *call* the business layer. Also, fat models are a bad design because they mix up storage and business layers...

Comment: geez sorry.. :P I read too fast.. but I still think validation should be done in the models

Comment: Validation on models is deceptive because in a number of cases it won't be run - using [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update) or create for examples.